# how to redirect a html page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on the Javascript page for my registration form. I simply just can't figure out how to make the page redirect to another page if everything's filled out.

```
document.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
  let allAreFilled = true;
  document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function(i) {
    if (!allAreFilled) return;
    if (!i.value) allAreFilled = false;
    if (i.type === "radio") {
      let radioValueCheck = false;
      document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll(`[name=${i.name}]`).forEach(function(r) {
        if (r.checked) radioValueCheck = true;
      })
      allAreFilled = radioValueCheck;
    }
  })
  if (!allAreFilled) {
    alert('Fill all the fields');
  }
  else {
    window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
  }
};
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to explain your problem more clearly. It's not apparent what's wrong.

Comment: @Rustyjim, answers go down there and should be accompanied by some explanation. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. A bunch of the checks you perform are probably superfluous to the problem. The element that triggers the onclick and its relationship to the form are probably relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving my sample script for the same possible problem I hope this helps

**HTML**

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<p id=P >Fill in all checkboxes</p>
    <form>
        <input type=radio />
        <label>Check 1</label>
        
        <input type=radio />
        <label>Check 2</label>
        
        <input type=radio />
        <label>Check 3</label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = () => 
{

var radio = document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]'),
p = document.getElementById("P");
 
radio.forEach( 
    function(i)
    {
        i.onchange = () => 
        {
            var checked = document.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]:checked"),
                leftover = radio.length - checked.length;
            p.innerHTML = "leftover checkbox " + leftover;
            
            if(radio.length == checked.length)
            {
                alert("All checked");
                window.location.href = "https://ilhamb.com/";
            }
            
        }
    }
)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use window.location.href to redirect within the same tab /window or use window.open() to redirect in a new tab /window.

As Quentin pointed out, you are already using an appropriate way to redirect. May I suggest opening the console and checking if there are console errors ? Also make sure that your program actually reaches the redirect by using a browser breakpoint or console logs.

Comment: They're already using [location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: Question already had a working element and author has a problem with smth else.

Answer (score -1):

This code

```
window.location = "w3schools.com"
```

Or

```
window.location.href = "w3schools.com"
```

should do it

Comment: `window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");` (which they are already using) should work fine. Using a different, but closely related, method isn't likely to address the actual problem. Omitting the scheme from the URL will point them at the wrong URL.